# Run scheduled background job on stateful service in azure service fabric to update some data in Reliable Dictionary on schedule time

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Is there away to run scheduled background job on stateful service in azure service fabric ? the only way I found only was timers & reminders which they run on Actors not stateful service. I'm trying to run scheduled background job to clean up some data in Reliable dictionary.

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773542/5946937

Comment: @LoekD, I'm using stateful service not Actors so Actors reminders& timers won't be applicable in this case for us. As far as RunAsync I read that it needs to be existed as soon as possible so it doesn't lock the Reliable collections. so not sure if implementing if added thread sleep or task.delay within infinite loop will cause any issues in the runtime since we still need to use that service's listeners for API client. Did I get this wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the default [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) way? So register this background task at you Host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to run background jobs in Service Fabric is to simply override the `RunAsync` operation. This works equally fine for stateful and stateless services - although, as already mentioned, `Actors` provide some additional functionality with its built in support for reminders and timers.

Below is a very basic example

```
public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // do something
    var nextWakeup = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    await Task.Delay(nextWakeup, cancellationToken);
}
```

If you require something more complex, you can for example, enhance the above to use the `IReliableStateManager` to manage your own collection of reminders.

Comment: Will it cause any issues or locks if Its accessing the same Reliable collections as the user calls ? so in example I'm trying to delete something in the RunAsync and user called the same collection using service remoting to perform something ? I'm referring to that warning in the Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle)

Comment: The reliable collection in stateful service is thread safe and designed for multi-threaded use - it also supports transactions. RunAsync has been designed for long running background tasks so your use case is fine. I recommend you have a look at [Working with reliable collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections).

Comment: Also, note that if you have infinite loop, as per above example, ensure you check and use the cancellation token to break out early. This ensures that Service fabric can terminate and re-create your service as per design (e.g. to relocate it to another node, etc).